# Google Analytics (screenviews and pageviews using same tracking ID)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-analytics

I am trying to send screenviews and pageviews using the same tracking ID with an AngularJS web app but I keep getting this error:

> Access denied. Please try relaunching In-Page Analytics from the report.[Error: 20010]

In index.html before the closing head tag, I have:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

and in the app.html before the closing head tag, I have:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto', {
        'appName': 'myApp'
    });
</script>
```

Since I am using AngularJS, within the body of the app.html there is a `<div ui-view></div>` which grabs all of the app views, and within that at the top before the html of each view I do this:

```
<script>
    ga('send', 'screenview', {screenName: 'dashboard'});
</script>
```

The screenName property would change based on the view, but they all use the same appName.

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong? I followed the documentation and I don't see why I'm getting this error. Is it because I am using the same tracking ID for both pageviews and screenviews? If so, how can I go around this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should work for the website only, for the app you need to create a new property on Google Analytics and configure it as a Mobile App Property, like the image below.

[mobile_app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDwrx.png)

When you create the new property, change the tracking ID on mobile to the new one.

For the website, check if the website link is correct on Property settings.

Regards, 
Vítor Capretz